# Python deleting node in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python

I am implementing an iterative solution for deleting a node in a BST given the root of the tree and the key of the node to delete.

I have two helper functions that returns the successor and the predecessor of the node in a BST.

```
def successor(root):
    root = root.right
    while root.left:
        root = root.left
    return root
```

and

```
def predecessor(root):
    root = root.left
    while root.right:
        root = root.right
    return root
```

In my main function, I first search the target node and search for the node to replace the target node, change the value, and then delete (set it to None) the successor/predecessor node.

```
def deleteNode(self, root: TreeNode, key: int) -> TreeNode:

        if not root:
            return None
        dummy = TreeNode(-1)
        dummy.left = root
        while root:
            if root.val < key:
                root = root.right
            elif root.val > key:
                root = root.left
            elif root.val == key:
                break

        if not root.left and not root.right:
            root = None
        elif root.right:
            succ = successor(root)
            root.val = succ.val
            root = root.right
            while root.left:
                root = root.left
            root = None
        elif root.left:
            pred = predecessor(root)
            root.val = succ.val
            pred = None
            root = root.left
            while root.right:
                root = root.right
            root = None
        return dummy.left
```

However, for some reason, the predecessor/successor node does not get deleted even though I go to the node and set it to `None`. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: It's reviewed quite well here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/ I will check your code as well.

Comment: Yeah, I've done it recursively and tried to do it iteratively, but I had that issue.

Comment: I don't think `root = None` "deletes" the node at all. What you should do is to be at the node the leaf of which you want to delete and have `root.right = None` *etc.*